# mSL Scripting with LastFM API

Tags: irc, mirc

I'm having a issue with my mIRC script. Im trying to create a channel trigger !lfm  the results will show the Artist, Genre, Plays

```
; Set your Last.fm API key here
alias SetAPIKey {
  return API_KEY
}

on *:TEXT:.lfm *:#: {
  ; Store the artist name from the message
  var %artist = $2

  ; Get the API key from a separate function
  var %apiKey = $SetAPIKey()

  ; Open the connection to Last.fm
  LastFMOpen %artist %apiKey
}

; Handle socket errors
alias sockError {
  if ($sockerr) { 
    notice $nick 04ERROR: $sock($sockname).wsmsg
    return 
  }
}

; Open the connection to Last.fm
alias LastFMOpen {
  var %artist = $1
  var %apiKey = $2

  sockclose get.connectLastFm
  sockopen -ea get.connectLastFm ws.audioscrobbler.com 443
}

on *:sockopen:get.connectLastFm:{ 
  $sockError
  sockwrite -n $sockname GET /2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist= $+ %artist $+ &api_key=API_KEY&format=json
  sockwrite -n $sockname Host: ws.audioscrobbler.com
  sockwrite -n $sockname
}

on *:sockread:get.connectLastFm:{
  sockread -f %line
  msg $chan [Artist Name: ]-[ Genre: ]-[ Plays: ]-
  unset %line
}
```

I tried  changing the socket events and got no luck. I do have a current active API number to use

Comment: What is the issue you are experiencing? Also try doing `sockwrite -tn` instead of just `-n`